# == condition is not working in rendered attribute of <apex:pageBlockSection>

Tags: apex, visualforce

VF CODE SNIPPET

```
<apex:pageBlockSection id="abcd" title="Closed Lost Information" rendered="{!(Opportunity.StageName=='Closed Lost')}">
        <apex:inputField label="Opportunity Name" value="{!Opportunity.Reason_Lost__c}"/><p/>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

I am new to salesforce and I am having below question. As shown in above snippet, I need to render the **"apex:pageBlockSection"** if StageName value is equal to 'Closed Lost'. (StageName is a picklist of standard object opportunity)

Here the condition is not returning proper true or false value to render or hide the **"apex:pageBlockSection"** .

Can anybody please help me to figure out what is wrong with my approach ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use a Boolean variable instead of hard coded directly pick list value.And to set value to Boolean variable create an extension or custom controller and create a condition may be it works @user3240292

Comment: rendered="{!(Opportunity.StageName='Closed Lost')} ? (single equal sign?)

Comment: I am using == for equality comparison .

Comment: Suggest you include `<apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.StageName}"/>` in the page too while debugging to be sure of the value.

Comment: Is the record you are testing with definitely 'Closed Lost' at the point you are rendering this component? i've mocked up this example quickly and it looks to work correctly with the syntax you've given.

Comment: Can you wrap your pageblocksection in outputpanel and add rendered condition for outputpanel instead of pageblocksection and try.

Comment: @javanoob : I tried like below( as per your suggestion ) :      <br/>                  `<apex:outputPanel id="abcd" rendered="{!If(Opportunity.StageName='Closed Lost',true,false)}">  
  
  <apex:pageBlockSection  title="Closed Lost Information">
        <apex:inputField label="Opportunity Name" value="{!Opportunity.Reason_Lost__c}"/><p/>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:outputPanel>`  <br/>  but this also not working :(

Comment: @user3240292, can you try using == instead of =??

Comment: Yes I tried both ways.

Comment: @user3240292, we can discuss in this room. Click this link https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37748/condition-is-not-working-in-rendered-attribute-of-apexpageblocksection

Comment: @user3240292 Did you solve the problem? or do you still need help?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you'd use a boolean variable, but you can also use an If statement to achieve the same results. Try the following for the rendered expression:

```
rendered="{!If(Opportunity.StageName='Closed Lost',true,false)}
```

Comment: As `Opportunity.StageName=='Closed Lost'` is already a boolean expression, I don't see why wrapping that boolean in a boolean function will help. Can you explain?

Comment: I also tried using  rendered="{!If(Opportunity.StageName=='Closed Lost',true,false)}

Comment: My bad, should have been one = sign. Have edited answer.

Comment: Do you mean = (single equalto) sign will be used for comparison instead of == ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant to say and post when I copy pasted. Apologies for the misdirection. Is simply a workaround if your original code didn't work.

Comment: I tried it with single equal to but not working :(..

Answer (score 1):

it got solved..by making below change :

```
<apex:outputPanel id="abcd"> 
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Closed Lost Information" rendered="{!opportunity.stageName == 'Closed Lost'}" > 
<apex:inputField label="Opportunity Name" value="{!Opportunity.Reason_Lost__c}"/><p/> 
</apex:pageBlockSection> 
</apex:outputPanel>
```

i.e moved renedered attribute under pageblock section and rendered block under outputpanel

Comment: Just so you know I tried the rendered attribute on outputpanel and it is working for me. There really is no need to move to the pageBlockSection.

Comment: This answer only makes sense if the issue was a rerender and not the initial rendering. During the initial render it will be evaluated properly but the original question if you try to rerender the pageblocksection it will not work. Maybe the question did not adequately describe the problem